# Merge like consolidation of dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge

Based on the following data frames:

```
df1<-data.frame(ast = c('MMM', 'ABT','AES'), aloc = c(0.4140585, 0.3599352,0.2260063))
df2<-data.frame(ast = c('MMM','ABT','AFL', 'AES','A'), aloc =c(0.2493530, 0.2478328, 0.1720778, 0.1702486, 0.1604878))
df3<-data.frame(ast = c('ABT','MMM','ADBE','AFL','AMD' ), aloc =c(0.2578605, 0.2540922, 0.2183000, 0.1364096, 0.1333377 ))
```

I would like to do something like merge (although I couldn't do it with merge) to obtain the following result:

```
#       Df1       Df2       Df3 
A        NA        NA    0.1604878
ABT  0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
ADBE     NA        NA    0.2183000
AES  0.2260063 0.1702486      NA
AFL     NA     0.1720778 0.1364096
AMD     NA         NA    0.1333377
MMM  0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = "ast") %>% 
  full_join(., df3, by = "ast") %>%
  setNames(c(names(.)[1], paste0("df", 1:3))) %>%
  arrange(ast)
```

Which gives:

```
#   ast       df1       df2       df3
#1    A        NA 0.1604878        NA
#2  ABT 0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
#3 ADBE        NA        NA 0.2183000
#4  AES 0.2260063 0.1702486        NA
#5  AFL        NA 0.1720778 0.1364096
#6  AMD        NA        NA 0.1333377
#7  MMM 0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922
```

---

Or as per mentionned by @RichardScriven:

```
Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by = "ast"), list(df1, df2, df3)) %>% arrange(ast)
```

If you have a lot of `df` in your global environment in the form of df<sub>n</sub> you could also do:

```
dflist <- ls(pattern = "df[1-9]")
Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by = "ast"), lapply(dflist, get)) %>%
  setNames(c(names(.)[1], dflist)) %>% 
  arrange(ast)
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant; but I prefer to rename the columns first, so the merges are automatic:  `full_join(rename(df1, df1=aloc), rename(df2, df2=aloc)) %>% full_join(rename(df3, df3=aloc))`

Comment: Another option (better for more data frames) is `Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by = "ast"), list(df1, df2, df3)) %>%
    arrange(ast)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use merge:

```
df1<-data.frame(ast = c('MMM', 'ABT','AES'), aloc = c(0.4140585, 0.3599352,0.2260063))
df2<-data.frame(ast = c('MMM','ABT','AFL', 'AES','A'), aloc =c(0.2493530, 0.2478328, 0.1720778, 0.1702486, 0.1604878))
df3<-data.frame(ast = c('ABT','MMM','ADBE','AFL','AMD' ), aloc =c(0.2578605, 0.2540922, 0.2183000, 0.1364096, 0.1333377 ))

df1$df1 <- df1$aloc
df2$df2 <- df2$aloc
df3$df3 <- df3$aloc

df1$aloc <- NULL
df2$aloc <- NULL
df3$aloc <- NULL

data <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ast", all = TRUE)
data <- merge(data, df3, by = "ast", all = TRUE)

data
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`sqldf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) can be used for things like this. It let's you treat data frames as SQL tables, and perform SQL queries on them:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select a.ast, df1.aloc as df1, df2.aloc as df2, df3.aloc as df3
       from (select ast from df1 union select ast from df2 union select ast from df3) as a
           left join df1 on a.ast = df1.ast
           left join df2 on a.ast = df2.ast
           left join df3 on a.ast = df3.ast')
##    ast       df1       df2       df3
## 1    A        NA 0.1604878        NA
## 2  ABT 0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
## 3 ADBE        NA        NA 0.2183000
## 4  AES 0.2260063 0.1702486        NA
## 5  AFL        NA 0.1720778 0.1364096
## 6  AMD        NA        NA 0.1333377
## 7  MMM 0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922
```

The `sqldf()` function returns a data frame, and you can manipulate it as such:

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[,-1]
df
##            df1       df2       df3
## A           NA 0.1604878        NA
## ABT  0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
## ADBE        NA        NA 0.2183000
## AES  0.2260063 0.1702486        NA
## AFL         NA 0.1720778 0.1364096
## AMD         NA        NA 0.1333377
## MMM  0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922
```

Answer (score 1):

So here are two solutions. These have the advantage over the other solutions (wx the tidyr solution) that you can work with an arbitrary number of data.frames by just changing the first line (`lst <- ...`).

```
library(reshape2)
lst <- list(df1,df2,df3)
df <- do.call(rbind,lst)
df <- cbind(df.name=rep(1:length(lst),sapply(lst,nrow)),df)
result <- dcast(df,ast~df.name)
result[order(as.character(result$ast)),]
#    ast         1         2         3
# 4    A        NA 0.1604878        NA
# 1  ABT 0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
# 6 ADBE        NA        NA 0.2183000
# 2  AES 0.2260063 0.1702486        NA
# 5  AFL        NA 0.1720778 0.1364096
# 7  AMD        NA        NA 0.1333377
# 3  MMM 0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922


library(data.table)
lst <- list(df1,df2,df3)
df <- do.call(rbind,lst)
setDT(df)[,df.name:=rep(1:length(lst), sapply(lst,nrow))]
result <- dcast.data.table(df,ast~df.name, value.var="aloc")
result[,ast:=factor(ast, levels=sort(levels(ast)))]
setkey(result,ast)
result
#     ast         1         2         3
# 1:    A        NA 0.1604878        NA
# 2:  ABT 0.3599352 0.2478328 0.2578605
# 3: ADBE        NA        NA 0.2183000
# 4:  AES 0.2260063 0.1702486        NA
# 5:  AFL        NA 0.1720778 0.1364096
# 6:  AMD        NA        NA 0.1333377
# 7:  MMM 0.4140585 0.2493530 0.2540922
```

Both of these bind the data.frames together row-wise, with a column, `df.name` to indicate which data.frame that row belongs to, then casts from long format to wide format. The `data.table` solution is likely to be much faster with large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

First we can make a long dataframe using rbind:

```
rbinddf <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Then we need an id column from the originals:

```
rbinddf$id <- unlist(lapply(1:3, function(n, i){rep(paste0("df", i), nrow(n[[i]]))}, n = list(df1, df2, df3)))
```

Then it's a simple reshape - we can use `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(rbinddf, id, aloc)
```